# [javascript]Access to elements of random website

Tags: javascript, element

is there any possibility to access to elements of random website like for example "google.com". If you right click on it you can inspect elements, and I would like to use them in my script. You know how to do it?

P.S when I was working with c# or c++(Qt) there were few methods that allows me to access, and they had the same syntax like in javascript.

I just want to mention that when I use document.getElementById("xxx"), I think the method is looking for id's in my html file not in external.

Comment: You can on the google chrome console. You can access the dom directly. It sounds what you want to do is malicious though.

Comment: Yes, you can get those elements with javascript, if your javascript environment isn't bound by the same-origin policy. Once such environment is node.js, however node.js won't run in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

The standard security context for a web browser prevents JavaScript on a site from instructing a visitor's browser to get data from another site (using the visitor's credentials) and then making that available to the JS from the first site.

If it was possible then Alice could follow a link Mallory's website and then have Mallory's site's JavaScript access Alice's bank's website and give all of Alice's account information to Mallory. This is obviously undesirable.

JavaScript running in a browser extension can (the specifics depend on the browser the extension is being written for).

JavaScript running in non-browser contexts (such as Node.js or the Windows Scripting Host) can (again, the specifics depend on the environment).